# Firebase doesnt sync with android studio if have more than 20 flavors

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I have a project with 47 flavors (And it keep growing) its just an app for streaming radio, the project is using firebase to send push notifications.
when i start it i sync directly from android studio throw the assistant with no problem, when i reach flavor number 30 (not exactly) android studio start to say project sync fail (with firebase), any chance to repair it? I'm too busy to do it manually all time.

Comment: Why do you need 47 flavors??

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/